# Tensorflow2 warning using @tffunction

Tags: tensorflow

This example code from Tensorflow 2

```
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer("/tmp/mylogs/tf_function")

@tf.function
def my_func(step):
  with writer.as_default():
    # other model code would go here
    tf.summary.scalar("my_metric", 0.5, step=step)

for step in range(100):
  my_func(step)
  writer.flush()
```

but it is throwing warnings.

> WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 5 calls to  triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive
>   and the excessive number of tracings is likely due to passing python
>   objects instead of tensors. Also, tf.function has
>   experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes
>   that can avoid unnecessary retracing. Please refer to
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/eager/tf_function#python_or_tensor_args
>   and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for more
>   details.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`tf.function` has some "peculiarities". I highly recommend reading this article: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance

In this case, the problem is that the function is "retraced" (i.e. a new graph is built) every time you call with a different *input signature*. For tensors, input signature refers to shape and dtype, but for Python numbers, *every new value* is interpreted as "different". In this case, because you call the function with a `step` variable that changes every time, the function is retraced every single time as well. This will be extremely slow for "real" code (e.g. calling a model inside the function).

You can fix it by simply converting `step` to a tensor, in which case the different values will *not* count as a new input signature:

```
for step in range(100):
    step = tf.convert_to_tensor(step, dtype=tf.int64)
    my_func(step)
    writer.flush()
```

or use `tf.range` to get tensors directly:

```
for step in tf.range(100):
    step = tf.cast(step, tf.int64)
    my_func(step)
    writer.flush()
```

This should not produce warnings (and be much faster).

Comment: Does this problem make slower code execution also without using `@tf.function`?

Comment: No, because then there is no graph to be built/retraced.

Comment: `@tf.function` takes only tensor not scaler type. To convert to tensor is good to go.

Answer (score 5):

## Try this

I used `model(x)` instead of `model.predict(x)` And it worked for me

And if you are getting this error in a custom function, add a fixed signature of `shape` and `dtype` for your function.

```
@tf.function(input_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32),))
def next_collatz(x):
...
```

Comment: why does it work?