# Repeating the training loop of a keras model and getting warning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have implemented a VAE model and want to train it several times on the same data from scratch in a loop so that I do not have to start it manually again.

While the training kind of works I always get the following warning message:

```
out of the last 5 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x7f102c312820> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors
```

My training loop:

```
for z in range(3):
    z+=1
    for i in mvt:
        #i+=1
        vae = 0
        start = time.time()
        train_data_dir ='...'

        nb_train_samples = 1466 
        nb_validation_samples = 141 
        nb_epoch = 100
        batch_size = 8  
        img_width = 64
        img_height = 64                     

        es_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_total_loss', patience=5)

        train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                rescale=1./255,
                validation_split=0.1,
                )

        test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

        train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                train_data_dir,
                subset="training",
                target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                color_mode="rgb",
                batch_size=batch_size,
                #shuffle = False,
                class_mode=None)

        val_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                train_data_dir, 
                subset="validation",
                target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                color_mode="rgb",
                batch_size=batch_size,
                #shuffle = False,
                class_mode=None)

        vae = VAE()

        vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0002, decay=0.00001))

        vae_train = vae.fit(
                train_generator,
                steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
                epochs=nb_epoch,
                validation_data=val_generator,
                validation_steps=nb_validation_samples, #141 #3963
                callbacks=[es_callback]
                )
```

Does somebody know how to solve this?

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972225/tensorflow2-warning-using-tffunction help ?

Comment: tried it, but I got another python error in my fit function because of the changed integers to tensors